# How to load different structure json files with C# and display data in one html table?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Assuming there are two json files below:

```
 [{"A": 1,"B": 2},{"A": 3,"B": 4}]
```

another one's structure is,

```
  [{"B": 5,"C": 6}]
```

The number and structure  of json files are uncertain，how to load the two json file with C# and display in one html table like as :

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It makes me scratch my head with json.net for these days.Thanks in advance.

Comment: loop throgh json array and check whether it matches with column header and if matches then position the value in appropriate position

Comment: Which part of the problem are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through json and identify all possible columns. In your example A, B, C.

When generating html, generate headers for all identified columns and for each json object, generate a table row, placing values in their corresponding `<td>`:

1st td for A, 2nd td for B, etc.